# Question about series and how the pattern idea works

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, analysis, number-theory

Two Questions:

When you are given:

$1, 2, 3, .... , n$

How do you know that in the $...$ that it continues the $x_{n-1} + 1$ pattern?

Is it the **definition of series?**

Secondly:

Do partial sums **always** carry the same pattern. Suppose you find out the first FOUR partial sums.

$P1 = 1/2, P2 = 1/2 + 1/2, P3 = 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2, P4 = 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2$

Why can you find the general $nth$ partial sum? How do you know that $P583929$ does **not** change the pattern eg. If $P48882 = 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/2 .... + 1/3$?

How do you know this?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) Both common sense and, in particular, common agreement among mathematicians. It is not the definition of **series** but rather the way to write shortly the first $\;n\;$ natural numbers. 2) In a *general series* it can be between very hard and up to impossible to know the general pattern. In *some* series there's a definite formula that can allow us to know either what's the n-th term of the sum or the sum of the first n elements. In your example, **and unless otherwise stated**, it is *understood* that the pattern of sum of $\;\frac12$'s continues on and on.

Comment: @Timbuc, thanks for the reply; **Question:** I think it is better to **write before the answer:** "assuming," the sequence carries the same pattern.... [answerHere]. What do you say?

Comment: @Timbuc. Any idea?

Comment: if you want to be annoyingly accurate I guess you can write that. In usual mathematical writing, when writing down something being numbered by the naturals, the three dots mean the whatever is being written continues with the same pattern as the first elements. This can be dangerous, though:  $\;3,\,5\ldots\;$ can be continued as $\;3,5,7,9,11,\ldots\;$ (the odd naturals beginning with three) , as $\;3,5,7,11,13,\ldots\;$ (the odd primes), $\;3,5,8,13,21,\ldots\;$ (Fibonacci sequence beginning with $\;3,5\;$), etc. So one **must** be sure the sequence is pitch clear from the written .

Comment: @Timbuc, okay, so it is the DEFINITION of the three dots then?? Thanks

Comment: @Timbuc, please, I would really REALLY appreciate it! PLEASE?

Comment: I don't know if that's the definition of the three dots, but I guess you could try to google it. I know that's what most, or at least many, mathematicians understand.